# WPF user interface with long processing execution hangs

Tags: wpf, multithreading, process, background, dispatcher

I am extremely Sorry for this long post. I need some help on c# wpf issues. I have build a complicated UI(somehow) and there is some buttons... like start and stop and others.

When i click the start button a execution process starts with communicating with some protocol layer and others and it is a long process .. and during this process i have to show some notification UI like "Enter a Text", "Select Something" etc... this time i have to show some wpf window object... and after some time i have to automatically destroy the window and go with processing again.

At first i tried to run the execution in the Main window class. But it results that when the execution starts.. user can't click anything and ui doesno't respond rather just hangs. I investigate the problem... and found that UI is busy with processing in the execution on protocol layer so its not responding.

Here is my problem... can u give me some solution that...

1. i will have 2 button..start and stop
2. when i click the start button... a large process will start( like nested for loop with a large int which will continue for 50 seconds) in function named Processor.
3. at time of processing the function Processor will create several window and show them wait for 5-10 seconds and also destroy them. or user click;s on the window
4. And the whole time the stop button should be clickable so that when i click the stop button .. the process should be stop.

I tried this with backgroundworker, dispatcher... and using separate thread. but no luck. I guess i am missing something. because if i wait for some result showing a window..the window will definitely hang.. and if i separate them with different thread.. it will not communicate with each other.  please give me some suggestions

Comment: The `Dispatcher` may still lock the UI up if it is extremely CPU intensive, however a `BackgroundWorker` should work fine. Can you show us the code you tried with the BackgroundWorker?

Answer (score 0):

`Dispatcher` is definitely the solution. You may need to set the [Dispatcher Priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx). Sharing some relevant code may also reveal some issues.

Comment: Dispatcher still uses the main UI thread, and can cause it to lock up during CPU intensive operations.

Comment: @Rachel - that is why I suggested that thread priority should be used to assign which thread should have which priority (*UI vs Worker*).

Comment: @SilverNinja I've had it lock up the UI even with a different DispatcherPriority. I tested at the lowest possible priority (`SystemIdle`) before I gave up and switched to using background threads. This was for a CPU intensive operation though, not something like a database call that was waiting for a reply.

Comment: @Rachel - good to know. I usually offload CPU-intensive ops to another system (*database, service call, etc.*) and have never seen this lockup you encountered.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. In the processor function i am using the AutoResetEvent and Timer. I am checking in every 200 miliseccond for the response of the protocol layer. So, when i start the process using dispatcher / backgroundworker normally it usually hangs as the processor function is waiting and checking using timer

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker should do what you need.  Set WorkerSupportsCancellation and WorkerReportsProgress to true.

I wouldn't suggest popping up multiple windows.  Pop up one window to display status.  In your loop in DoWork, call BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress.  Then in the ProgressChanged event handler, update the status of the window.

To implement Stop:
In your DoWork method you need to check the CancellationPending property on the BackgroundWorker in your loop.  When it is true you need to exit that method.  On the stop button click, call BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync().

Comment: yes it works. But when i tried to create a new instance of a wpf window within the function reportProgress... it always shows the InvalidOperation exception that... "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." can u suggest anything so that i can create a instance of a window and show it within.. the backgroundworker process. I will destroy this when user clicks the Cancel Button.

Comment: Now i can run a process in a backgroundworker and can update a textBox at times of executing this process. But the main problem is i can't create a new instance of another wpf window in that backgroundworker. I have searched in the stackoverflow and found that it is not possible(!). the back..worker    uses MTA thread where at times of creating of new window requires STA thread. Please suggest some way

Comment: there is a detailed article here with an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx
You shouldn't modify the UI in the DoWork event handler.  Instead update the UI in ProgressChanged or RunWorkerCompleted.